# What is that .libs directory in the Desktop

Tags: 21.10, malware

What is that `.libs` directory in the Desktop created by, usually? I've just seen it for the first time. It contains nothing in it, but I am suspicious of it as I haven't run anything on the Desktop recently. I run a lot of `gcc` and compile all the time, but not on the Desktop. My `gcc` commands do not contain any .libs in the command. My programs do not write/create any files/folders called .libs. `history | grep libs` shows no command containing libs.

Side note: Since 21.10, I've been seeing other directories such as `firefox.tmp` in the Downloads folder. But that is obviously firefox's snap version's way of things.

`ls -la Desktop`:

```
drwxrwxr-x  2 user user      4096 Nov 24 00:00  .libs
```

It says 'Nov 24', but it wasn't there till today.

By my screenshots in the past, I am pretty sure that this was not there by default after the installation of Ubuntu.

Comment: Can you do ls on your Desktop ? Paste the output here.

Comment: `ls -a`. Normal `ls` won't show `.libs` ;-)

Comment: @pLumo, I know that, no problem :) Edited, see question

Comment: Ok, now you know when it was last modified :-) Exactly 00:00 ? maybe some cronjob?

Comment: @pLumo, I don't know anything about cron. I have heard it schedules jobs and runs them, thats all

Comment: Screenshots? Where do you see this dir? It shouldn't be visible in the graphical desktop since it's a hidden directory.

Comment: @terdon, it is visible on the graphical desktop. I have hidden directories enabled. *Where do you see this dir*, The title says I see it in the Desktop folder, I only have one user in the home folder on my system, i.e. the one created during installation

Comment: @pLumo any help?